# What is the location of .sh file of the jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for the location of .sh file which is generated my jenkins job and can be found in console output. This .sh files starts with jenkins word.

I am using AWS instance for jenkins.

i was looking for /temp folder, but didn't get into /tmp folder.

sample of the .sh file name:

[first_gitbuild] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins8581903656897699418.sh

Answer (score 0):

These files are deleted when job finishes.

I was able to get a copy of this .sh files with these steps:

- Set a sleep in my script ( 5 mins )
- Build the job
- Go to /tmo folder and copy paste the script : /tmp/jenkins......sh